# Azure Storage Table Does not return whole partition

Tags: azure, storage

I found some situation on production when

```
CloudContext.TableData.Where( A => A.PartitionKey == "MYKEY").ToList();
```

where TableData is

```
public DataServiceQuery<T> TableData { get { return CreateQuery<T>( _TableName ); } }
```

does not return the whole partition (I have less than 1000 records there).

In my case it returns 367 records while in VS2010 Server Explorer or in Azure Storage Explorer I get 414 records (condition is the same).

Did anyone experience the same problem?

Also If I change the query and add RowKey into the condition - I get required record with no problem.

Comment: Based on the solutions before:
Modified code:
TableData -> CreateQuery<T>(_TableName).AsTableServiceQuery<T>();
ToList() -> 

public static List<TSource> ToFullList<TSource>( this IQueryable<TSource> Source )
  {
   if( Source == null )
   {
    throw new ArgumentNullException( "Source" );
   }

   return Source.AsTableServiceQuery( ).Execute( ).ToList( );


  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known and documented behavior. The Table service API will either return 1000 entities or as much entities as possible within 5 seconds. If the query takes longer than 5 seconds to execute, it'll return a continuation token.

With the addition of rowkey you are making the query more specific and hence faster and as a result yo are getting all the entities.

See [TimeOuts and Pagination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135718.aspx) on MSDN for details

Answer (score 1):

You have to better understand the Table Service. In the official documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135718.aspx) there are listed other conditions which affect number of records returned. If you want to retrieve the whole partition you have to inspect the TableResult for Continuation Token and use provided continuation token to execute the same query over and over again, until all the results come.

You can use an approach similar to the following:

```cs
    private IEnumerable<MyEntityType> GetAllEntities()
    {
        var result = this._tables.GetSegmentedEntities(100, null); // null is for continuation token
        while (result.Results.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var ufs in result.Results)
            {
                yield return new MyEntityType(ufs.RowKey, ufs.WhateverOtherPropertyINeed);
            }
            if (result.ContinuationToken != null)
            {
                result = this._tables.GetSegmentedEntities(100, result.ContinuationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `GetSegmentedEntities(100, result.ContinuationToken)` is defined as:

```cs
    public TableQuerySegment<MyEntityType> GetSegmentedEntities(int pageSize, TableContinuationToken token)
    {
        var partKey = "My_Desired_Partition_key_passed_via_Const_or_method_Param";
        TableQuery<MyEntityType> query = new TableQuery<MyEntityType>()
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partKey));
        query.TakeCount = pageSize;
        return this.azureTableReference.ExecuteQuerySegmented<MyEntityType>(query, token);
    }
```

You can use and modify this code for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting partial result sets then there will be two factors.

i) You are having more than 1000 records matching the filter
 ii) Querying took more than 5 seconds.
 iii) Query crosses partition boundary.

As you are having less than 1000 records the first factor wont be a issue.And as you are retrieving based on PartitionKey equality third one also wont cause any problem. You are facing this problem because of second factor.

Two handle this you need to work on continuation token. You can refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135718.aspx) for more info.